# Can this be considered as a valid implementation of singleton class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, singleton

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Singleton {
public:
    int val;
    static int count;
    Singleton() {
        if (count == 1) throw 0;
        Singleton::count++;
        val = 100;
    }
};

int Singleton::count = 0;

int main () {
    try {
        Singleton a, b;
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "error\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So we count the number of objects created, and throw from the constructor when count is about to exceed 1. Will throwing from constructor abort the creation of object?

Comment: I haven't done C++ in 24 years, but surely you'd need some synchronization around `if (count == 1) throw 0;` and `Singleton::count++;`? Otherwise, Thread A can clear the `if (count == 1)` and before it does `Singleton::count++;` Thread B can also clear the `if (count == 1)` -- and you have two instances (at least).

Comment: What are your requirements for this class?

Comment: Putting synchronization issues aside, you remove compile time mechanisms to ensure singularity and proper lifetime, and replace them with a runtime error with *no mechanism* to address lifetime issues... this isn't better than the popular approach.

Comment: Are you trying to find out a proper way to implement a singleton in c++, or you just curios about this particular (very specific) code?

Comment: @AlanBirtles no requirement as such, I was just curious about this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 and above:

You make your constructor private and define a static instance in a static function. It synchronizes construction so the object is constructed once no matter how many threads try to access it:

```
class Singleton {
private:
    Singleton() { /* ... */ }

public:
    static auto& instance() {
        static Singleton singleton;
        return singleton;
    }
};
```

Pre C++11:

Before C++11 (C++03, C++98) there is no standard way to synchronize object construction. You need to use OS-specific tricks to make it work.

If you have a single-threaded program, and thus don't care about the synchronization, you can use the same version as above.

Comment: Note that this works only for C++11 compliant compilers and above.  Before C++11, you had to use synchronization.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, yes, but pre-C++11 the standard didn't acknowledge the existence of threads. And it's 2021, a decade after C++11 was standardized.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I still don't know the answer for second part, i.e, whether throwing an exception from class constructor aborts the creation of object? Also, How do we verify if object is created?

Comment: @VighneshNayak yes, throwing will abort construction. And the object is done constructing by the time you access it the first time.